# Using execv to do basic I/O

Tags: c++, exec

I'm trying to use execv() to allow me to read into an output file, outputfile.txt, from the terminal. The problem I'm having is that it won't work at all and I don't know if I'm using it correctly.

My code so far:

```
void my_shell() {
    char* args[2];
    args[0] = "/usr/bin/tee";
    args[1] = "outputfile.txt";
    execv(args[0], &args[0]);   
}

int main() {

    cout << "%";
    //string input;
    pid_t pid, waitPID;
    int status = 0;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        my_shell();
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        cout << "Unable to fork" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    while ((waitPID = wait(&status)) > 0) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What it's doing right now is that nothing is happening at all. The program forks fine, but what's in my_shell isn't doing anything at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the null terminator. Read the manual again, carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `NULL` terminator to `args`.

```
void my_shell() {
    char* args[3];
    args[0] = "/usr/bin/tee";
    args[1] = "outputfile.txt";
    args[2] = NULL;
    execv(args[0], args);   
}
```