# Calling "bash [script name]" in C

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am trying to run a bash script to generate an OpenSSL certificate. I have the bash script in the same directory as my c code.

Relevant C code:

```c
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid > 0){
    char* arr[] = {"./generate_cert.sh", "direct"};
    int succ = execv(arr[0], arr);
    printf("succ: %d\n", succ);
    exit(1);
}else if(pid < 0){
    printf("Fork failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

generate_cert.sh, My test bash script which I will eventually expand is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
```

It seems I have a permission denied with ./generate_cert.sh. I need to instead run bash generate_cert.sh. How do I do this with execv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System call fork() and execv function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147386/608639), [Using execv to do basic I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21618609/608639), etc.

Comment: That is not an error. use `perror("execv failed")` to get the **actual** error.

Comment: Thank you for that tip on perror. I am indeed getting a permission denied. Is there a way to instead run `bash generate_cert.sh`?

Comment: If I substitute "bash generate_cert.sh" for the first argument, I get error: "no such file or directory" since I am now not pointing to the script location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [execv man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) page, the array must be terminated by a null pointer.

So something along the lines of this (untested):

```
  char* arr[] = {"./generate_cert.sh", "direct",NULL};
  int succ = execv(arr[0], arr);
```

**Edit**:

OP's problem turned out to be the execute bit wasn't set on the script file. Which was solved by `chmod +x generate_cert.sh` , however another alternative would be to make the `execv` call to `/bin/bash` instead. I.e something along the lines of.

```
char* arr[] = {"/bin/bash", "./generate_cert.sh", "direct",NULL};
int succ = execv(arr[0], arr);
```

Comment: I tried this and I am still getting the error. When I try to run ./generate_cert.sh direct in my terminal I get "-bash: ./generate_cert.sh: Permission denied". I can however run bash generate_cert.sh direct and it runs successfully. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes that is a problem, you need `chmod +x generate_cert.sh`  to make the script executable

Comment: That was my problem. Thank you so much.